# Rexec with X11 forwarding - how can I do this on a Mac?

Tags: mac, xorg, x11-forwarding, openvms

I'm able to connect using Rexec with X11 forwarding from a Windows PC using [Mocha](http://www.mochasoft.dk/freeware/x11.htm), however I need to find a method of achieving the same from a Mac.

I doubt it makes any difference, but the remote host runs VMS.

Can anyone offer any pointers to get me up and running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I'm not familiar with Rexec, but if it's a standard x11 program then this should hopefully work.

First you'll need to install X11 on your Mac.  I don't think there's a stand alone installer available for download, but you should be able to install it from your Mac OS X Installation disk.  Should say something like Optional Extras.

I personally just install the full Xcode developer tools package which installs a bunch of required software for installing software from source code.

Next you'll need to to ssh to the box that will be running the X11 app.  Open Terminal (in Application > Utilities) and run the ssh command with the -Y flag (I used -Y instead of -X for security reasons.  If this doesn't seem to work you can use ssh -X instead, but it's not recommended. See the man page on ssh.):

```
ssh -Y username@hostname
```

Once logged in you can run the app from the command line (if it's in your $PATH):

```
./rexec
```

Hopefully that's all you need to do.  You might have better luck doing those two commands from xterm (instead of Terminal).  For more information on X11 forwarding from/to a Mac check out [Configuring and Running X11 Applications on Mac OS X](http://developer.apple.com/opensource/tools/runningX11.html) from Apple's website.

Comment: Thanks. I've added X11 from my install disk, unfortunately SSH isn't an option on the remote host.

I can telnet into the host, but that won't give me X forwarding. I'm told the way to connect to get X forwarding to work is via rexec (512/TCP).

Much like yourself, I'm not familiar with rexec at all.

Comment: Why is SSH not an option?

Comment: @Grawity: The host is a part of a industrial control system. We can't simply make changes without going through lengthy approval processes and testing. If there was a requirement for a change, it isn't a problem, but asking to add SSH just so I can connect from my mac isn't going to be approved.

I can connect via a windows PC, so it isn't a problem, it would just be nice not to have to use a Virtual Machine or to have to dig my laptop out.

Comment: Bryan: You could try pushing SSH as a "security improvement" (which it *is*; rexec and the like are quite insecure)... Anyway. In Unix-like server systems, you could set the remote `$DISPLAY` variable to, say, `12.34.56.78:0`, where `12.34.56.78` was your own external IP -- then X11 connections would be made directly over TCP. On VMS, http://h71000.www7.hp.com/faq/vmsfaq_017.html seems to have the answer. Don't forget to configure your X server (Mocha) and your router to accept X11 connections.